# Find Application which caused Application pool to crash (IIS 7)

Tags: c#, .net, iis, application-pool

I have an application pool been shared by multiple applications (not website!), looking through the event viewer, I've found an entry which states the cause for the crash.

In the event, it has the following field.

Application ID: /KL/W3SVC/12/ROOT/uk

Question, how do I use it to find the corresponding application in the IIS?

Comment: IIS 7 as stated in subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application ID: /KL/W3SVC/12/ROOT/uk

W3svc => IIS

Root => root application/website the app belongs to

UK  => Name of the application